# How to find out time spent by an user on a page of my website

Tags: php, html

I want to measure time spent by user on a particular webpage written in PHP and save the time in database. How can I do this? And please, can someone explain this to me?

```
var startTime = 0;
$(function() {
    startTime = Date.now();
});

$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
    $.ajax({async: false, // Necessary, because the closing code has
                          // to be suspended until the ajax succeeds
        url: 'store.php',
        data: {time: Date.now() - startTime},
        success: function(text) {
            // This is executed when the response has been received
            // text is response data
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest going with services like Google analytics as they provide a full solution for your request.

As for the above code, what is happening is that you're getting the timestamp of when the user enters your site, then getting another one when the user leaves (by using unload). Finally the above code subtracts them to get the total seconds spent.

The disadvantage of the above is that you will lose a lot of data because the unload might not have enough time to submit the request.
I also suggest you move all your code inside the "document ready".

### Suggestion

An alternate solution is to send requests to the server every X minutes telling it that the user is still here. This way you can roughly estimate how much time users are spending on your site.

P.S. If you are going to use the unload function provided by jQuery. Check out the documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/unload/

Comment: I agree. Google Analytics is your solution for speed. you get a fully working solution with graphs and filters and maps of the world, showing where you requests are coming from. Unless you have a business requirement for not having external code like googles running, then you are not going to get better than google analytics without a LOT of work.